# JSON to dict with class

Tags: json, swift, class

I decide some JSON and try to typecast it to a dictionary of String: classy and it fails. I have found that often the reason I have trouble doing something is because of a misunderstanding of how Swift works, so here is what I want to happen. Feel free to tell me that I am doing it wrong and if I do it this way all will be wonderful.

I want my data to live between runs of the app so I have to save the data to storage between runs. I have an object, data and associated code, and I have places where changes I make to a copy should reflect back to the original so it is a class. I have a bunch of these objects and most of the time I pick the one I want based on an id that is an integer. An array is not good since it would be a sparse array cause come ids are not used. I came up with a dictionary with a key of the id and data of the structure. I turned the key from an Int to a String, by changing the Int id to a String, cause converting a dictionary to JSON is MUCH easier for a key that is a string. I save the JSON string. When the app starts again I read the string in and convert the JSON string to Any. Then I typecast the result to the desired dictionary. This is where it fails. The cast does not work. In my Googling the samples I found said this should work.

Here is my code:

```
class Y: Codable, Hashable {
  var a: String = "c"
  static func ==(lhs: Y, rhs: Y) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a
  }
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
      hasher.combine(a)
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button ("Error") {
        var y = Y()
        var yDict = [String: Y]()
        yDict["0"] = y
        do {
          let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(yDict)
          let jsonString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)
          let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encodedData, options: [])
          if let yyDictDec = decoded as? [String:Y] {
            print("yDict after decide")
            print (yyDictDec)
          }
        } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        print("x")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this code the `if yyDictDec =` is failing, I think, cause the prints after it never happen. I can cast it as `[String, Any]` but I really need it to be my class.

My problem is in the convert JSON back to the dictionary. I feel I am missing something fairly simple.

Comment: You should `print(error)` instead of `error.localizedDescription` -- it'll give you more exact information about your error. In general, I'd say you need to include a [mre] here, as the description is pretty confusing. I'm not sure why you can't just use a `Codable` model of data and not try to convert in between ID types, have to use JSONSerialization, etc.

Comment: I think I have an example. If you create a SwiftUI app and replace the generated view with the code I included it produces the problem. In the sample catch never runs. The code runs without errors. The problem is that the if converting to my dictionary fails.

Comment: My class is codable. I am not trying to convert between types. I start out with a dictionary, [String: Y], convert it to JSON, so I can write it out. Then take the JSON and try to get it back to a dictionary. I left out the whole write/read from storage thing to create a simple example. The only conversion I do is in an attempt to get back the original thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t use `JSONSerialization` use `JsonDecoder` and decode it to the the type it was before encoding. e.g.:

```
let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Y].self, from: encodedData)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it and it works like a champ. Now to go off and try to understand it.

Comment: An advangage/disadvantage of most frameworks is that there are number of ways to do the same thing and not all of them are obvious. The code I had, JSONSerialization, was what I know and it did convert JSON into something. Now I kind of understand that JSONDecoder will convert JSON to specific objects so moving foreward I now how do decode to both stuff and specific objects.